# How to configure spring-boot servlet like in web.xml?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-boot

I have a simple servlet configuration in web.xml:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.atmosphere.cpr.MeteorServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.servlet</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>net.org.selector.animals.config.ComponentConfiguration</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

How can I rewrite it for SpringBootServletInitializer?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. If you want the exact same Spring application using Servlet 3.0 why are you defining a different Servlet type (MeteorServlet vs. DispatcherServlet)? The configuration class that you load in the web.xml isn't explicitly used anywhere. Also you extend `SpringBootServletInitializer` but don't appear to override the crucial `configure` method.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps an example of the code you astray. I need to configure the Meteor Servlet, as described in web.xml

Comment: Sorry, not following. The web.xml has a `DispatcherServlet`. If you want another kind of servlet as the default servlet use the code in the answer but a different servlet class (the bean name still has to be "DispatcherServlet" though).

Comment: Ah, I get it. I missed the meteor servlet declaration. I'll update the answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If I take your question at face value (you want a `SpringBootServletInitializer` that duplicates your existing app) I guess it would look something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class Restbucks extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(Restbucks.class, ComponentConfiguration.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public MeteorServlet dispatcherServlet() {
        return new MeteorServlet();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServletRegistration() {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet());
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
        params.put("org.atmosphere.servlet","org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet");
        params.put("contextClass","org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext");
        params.put("contextConfigLocation","net.org.selector.animals.config.ComponentConfiguration");
        registration.setInitParameters(params);
        return registration;
    }

}
```

See [docs on converting an existing app](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-convert-an-existing-application-to-spring-boot) for more detail.

But, rather than using Atmosphere, you are probably better off these days using the native Websocket support in Tomcat and Spring (see the [websocket sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-websocket) and [guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) for examples).

Comment: for additional url mappings use registration.addUrlMappings("/whatever/*", "/whatever2/*");

Comment: I found this posting while researching how to define a filter list for a Spring Boot servlet after an error message resulted from trying to allow anonymous access to a named servlet in a Spring Boot app.  Are you willing to comment?  Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36489253/api-url-has-an-empty-filter-list-in-spring-boot-security