# How to configure a servlet init-param in a Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot application (version 1.2.1.RELEASE) that uses Spring MVC, and I need to set the development init parameter on the JspServlet.  In web.xml this would have looked like the following:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
        ...
        <init-param>
            <param-name>development</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
         ...
</servlet>
```

I would have thought I could do something like this: [How to configure spring-boot servlet like in web.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389996/how-to-configure-spring-boot-servlet-like-in-web-xml), but I don't think I can just replace new MeteorServlet() with new JspServlet() and go on my way, as I am sure JspServlet.init(ServletConfig config) needs to be called with a valid ServletConfig.  And, of course if I do just try it without proper in initialization, the application gives me a null pointer exception (which occurs because the private transient JspRuntimeContext rctxt; is null):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.periodicEvent(JspServlet.java:361)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.backgroundProcess(StandardWrapper.java:679)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1381)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1349)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Also, we have a really hacky way to do this by implementing a TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory and providing a servlet where we override the init method and the getInitParameter method of the ServletConfig, but it is somewhat hateful, and so I am hoping there is a better way.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Lastly, the code that reads this init-param is in the org.apache.jasper.EmbeddedServletOptions class and appears to only look for a ServletConfig init param so I can't specify this as a context param (I don't think) with something awesome like server.context-parameters.name=value.

```
String development = config.getInitParameter("development");
if (development != null) {
    if (development.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
        this.development = true;
    } else if (development.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
        this.development = false;
    } else {
        if (log.isWarnEnabled()) {
            log.warn(Localizer.getMessage("jsp.warning.development"));
        }
    }
```

}

And if I try to hit the application anyway, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:646)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspUtil.makeJavaIdentifier(JspUtil.java:833)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspUtil.makeJavaIdentifier(JspUtil.java:806)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.getServletClassName(JspCompilationContext.java:332)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.getClassFileName(JspCompilationContext.java:504)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.isOutDated(Compiler.java:444)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.isOutDated(Compiler.java:408)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:557)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:335)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:291)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricFilterAutoConfiguration$MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.java:90)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:534)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: The answer that you've linked to should work. The `ServletRegistrationBean` will register the `JspServlet` with Tomcat and Tomcat will then call the `init(ServletConfig)` method. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I did try it, and thought it didn't work, because of the NullPointerException.  However upon further investigation init(ServletConfig) is being called on the servlet, and the jsp servlet is being initialized.  The null pointer is a result of JspServlet.periodicEvent() being called before the initialization so rctxt is null - but it appears to be set later.  Maybe my problem is that I don't know how to make the dispatcher servlet and jsp servlet work together.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could just add the parameters to your application.properties file as described here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html
Look for:
    server.jsp-servlet.init-parameters.*= # Init parameters used to configure the JSP servlet

For example:

```
server.jsp-servlet.init-parameters.development=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone found this link for me, and it appears to work great, so I am going to got with it, unless someone comes up with a better option - http://fqa.io/questions/28863340/springboot-embedded-tomcat-jspservlet-options

```
    @Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer customizer() {
    return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {

        @Override
        public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
            if (container instanceof TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
                customizeTomcat((TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container);
            }
        }

        private void customizeTomcat(
                TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat) {
            tomcat.addContextCustomizers(new TomcatContextCustomizer() {
                @Override
                public void customize(Context context) {
                    Wrapper jsp = (Wrapper) context.findChild("jsp");
                    jsp.addInitParameter("development", development);
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```