# Dispatcher Servlet in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, servlet-dispatching

In my Spring Boot application with packaging type as war, I am configuring Spring MVC. As I understand we don't have to configure Dispatcher Servlet manually. However, I old style of `web.xml` I used to configure Dispatcher Servlet and then I used to pass `contextClass` and `contextConfigLocation` as follows

```
<servlet>
    <description>
    </description>
    <display-name>DispatcherServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <description>contextClass</description>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <description>contextConfigLocation</description>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.xxx.yyy.jdorderspringmvcweb.config.SpringMvcConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

I belive this was to indicate that SpringMvcConfig (my custom class with spring mvc configuration) is the configuration class for Spring MVC..

However, In spring boot if the Dispatcher Servlet is configured Automatically, how can I pass my custom class to the dispatcher Servlet?

In my Spring Boot application, my SpringMvcConfig class extends from WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and is annotated with `@Configuration` class.

Answer (score 0):

Right in the configuration class which is annotated by @Configuration you could define your dispatcherServlet and pass init-parameter to it.

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServletRegistration() {
    ServletRegistrationBean registrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet());
    registrationBean.addInitParameter("contextClass","org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext");  
    registrationBean.addInitParameter("contextConfigLocation","com.xxx.yyy.jdorderspringmvcweb.config.SpringMvcConfig");
    return registrationBean;
}
```

Another way would be to create a paramter map and then set parameter for registration bean. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389996/how-to-configure-spring-boot-servlet-like-in-web-xml) stream shows how to do it.

Comment: You have not answered the question. Your code shows `dispatcherServlet()` but no indication is given of what this is or how it is defined - which is what the question asks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create a config class as follow:

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MySpringMvcDispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { DemoAppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```