# Is it possible to use Spring boot with web.xml and annotation based configurataion

Tags: spring-boot

I want to use Spring Boot with web.xml and servlet 3.1 configuration.Is there any example?

I want to define my context(Dispatcher servlet/SpringBootServletInitializer) in Web.xml mean time define all other configuration using annotation based.Ex want to load application.properties/yml values using pojos.

Need this type of configuration to deploy the app in Liberty profile as Liberty expecting application context in web.xml when using liberety global sharelib.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure spring-boot servlet like in web.xml?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389996/how-to-configure-spring-boot-servlet-like-in-web-xml)

Comment: @Patrick given link will provide replacement for web.xml but I need web.xml as well as annotation based configuration.